# Google Chrome takes 7 minutes to install via group policy

Tags: windows, group-policy, msi, chrome

When enabling the group policy 'auto update check period override' to disable all auto update checks deploying chrome via group policy takes 7 minutes to install

I get the following error in the event log.

The description for Event ID 0 from source gupdate cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event:

Service stopped

---

If I don't enable the policy installation is fine, but I do not want silent updates - i want to be able to roll out updates after we have tested them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behavior can be disabled by setting the policy value to 0. Additionally, NOGOOGLEUPDATEPING=1 can be passed to the installer to prevent the omaha ping. See http://crbug.com/80567 and http://crbug.com/96243 for details.

Answer (score 5):

It calls home. If it can't call home it will try for 7 minutes and then give up.